# Why is my function throwing a 'StopIteration' exception?

Tags: python, generator

I've got a function that calculates Pythagorean triples using a generator. However when i call `next(myfunc())` it throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path omitted", line 124, in <module>
    next(x)
StopIteration
```

Where `x = myfunc()`

Here is my function:

```
import math

def myfunc():
    i = 1
    for z in range(0, i):
        for y in range(0, z):
            for x in range(0, y):
                if (math.pow(x, 2) + math.pow(y, 2)) == math.pow(z, 2):
                    yield (x*y*z)
                    i += 1
```

Comment: That's normal. Any function with a `yield` in it will raise a StopIteration eventually. The problem is in whatever code is calling `next` without accounting for that possibility.

Comment: I tried using a try/except clause, but it doesn't operate the try and just raises the exception.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that your function does not yield anything because your range are probably messed up:

1. `z` goes from `0` to `i - 1` (`0`) - So you have only one loop `z = 0`
2. `y` goes from `0` to `z - 1` (`-1`) - See the problem?

So basically you're calling `next` on an "empty" generator, so you get a `StopIteration` exception.

Also note that `range(0, i)` is evaluated only once, just after `i = 1`, so incrementing `i` in your inner loop does not affect the bound of your outer loop, so it is a useless statement.

BTW, most of the time you do not have to call `next` manually, you should rather use a `for` loop:

```
for a in myfunc(): # The for loop handle the StopIteration exception for you
    print(a)
```

**Edit:** And you should not use `math.pow` to compute the square value of an integer because it is not accurate (floating point precision) and it is much more slower than doing `x * x`, so simply check `x * x + y * y == z * z` (or use python power notation `**`: `x ** 2 + y ** 2 == z ** 2`).

Comment: How would I go about incrementing i for each generator call then?

Comment: @madcrazydrumma By *generator call*, do you mean `next()` or `myfunc()`?